# How to pass card type while creating new CreditCardRequest in Braintree

Tags: payment, gateway, braintree

Is there any option to pass the card type (e.g. VISA,DISCOVER etc ) while create new Credit Card request is make in Braintree. And any validation if no type is pass to the request. I am unable to see any validation while no type is pass with the request.

Comment: Nope, Braintree doesn't accept card type to validate against the card number. You can do it client side if you want; that's fairly common.

Comment: @agf Thanks very much. One thing please suggest any parameter should be passed with the GET request to verify the url for creating webhook. I Have tried lot but my url is not verified.

Comment: Nope, nothing needs to be done beyond what we talked about in the other question. I would check your logs and add some debug statements, and contact our support team directly. They are the best people to help with that kind of thing.